# Split list by ID and store results into separate vectors

Tags: r

Given a list, which I converted to a dataframe, providing the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(list('value' = c(3.166667,3.166667,3.416667,3.291667,3.00,2.75), 'ID' = c(511,511,532,532,556,556)))

$value
[1] 3.166667 3.166667 3.416667 3.291667 3.000000 2.750000

$ID
[1] 511 511 532 532 556 556
```

I need to split my observations by `ID` into vectors. However, my attempt

```
X <- split(myList, myList$ID)
```

Results in the following structure:

```
$`511`
     value  ID
1 3.166667 511
2 3.166667 511

$`532`
     value  ID
3 3.416667 532
4 3.291667 532

$`556`
  value  ID
5  3.00 556
6  2.75 556
```

Whereas, I was hoping to get this structure (each row in the original df is a distinct variable)

```
$1
     value    ID
1    3.166667 511
3    3.416667 532
5    3.00     556

$2
     value    ID
2    3.166667 511
4    3.291667 532
6    2.75     556
```

How do I accomplish this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this easily with `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
split(df, rowid(df$ID))
#$`1`
#     value  ID
#1 3.166667 511
#3 3.416667 532
#5 3.000000 556

#$`2`
#     value  ID
#2 3.166667 511
#4 3.291667 532
#6 2.750000 556
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! :)

Comment: How do you apply this solution to nested lists?

Comment: @ComfortEagle  Could you please post as a new question with an example?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks. A new question is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154451/splitting-and-manipulating-nested-lists/45154738#45154738