# Splitting and manipulating nested lists

Tags: r, split

I'm trying to split a nested list by a group variable. Please consider the following structure:

```
> str(L1)
List of 2
 $ names:List of 2
  ..$ first: chr [1:5] "john" "lisa" "anna" "mike" ...
  ..$ last : chr [1:5] "johnsson" "larsson" "johnsson" "catell" ...
 $ stats:List of 2
  ..$ physical:List of 2
  .. ..$ age   : num [1:5] 14 22 53 23 31
  .. ..$ height: num [1:5] 165 176 179 182 191
  ..$ mental  :List of 1
  .. ..$ iq: num [1:5] 102 104 99 87 121
```

Now I need to produce two lists, which use both `L1$names$last` to splice, resulting in `L2` and `L3`, seen below:

**L2: Result grouped by `L1$names$last`**

```
> str(L2) 
List of 3
 $ johnsson:List of 2
  ..$ names:List of 1
  .. ..$ first: chr [1:2] "john" "anna"
  ..$ stats:List of 2
  .. ..$ physical:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ age   : num [1:2] 14 53
  .. .. ..$ height: num [1:2] 165 179
  .. ..$ mental  :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ iq: num [1:2] 102 99
 $ larsson :List of 2
  ..$ names:List of 1
  .. ..$ first: chr [1:2] "lisa" "steven"
  ..$ stats:List of 2
  .. ..$ physical:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ age   : num [1:2] 22 31
  .. .. ..$ height: num [1:2] 176 191
  .. ..$ mental  :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ iq: num [1:2] 104 121
 $ catell  :List of 2
  ..$ names:List of 1
  .. ..$ first: chr "mike"
  ..$ stats:List of 2
  .. ..$ physical:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ age   : num 23
  .. .. ..$ height: num 182
  .. ..$ mental  :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ iq: num 87
```

**L3: Each group only permits one occurrence of `L1$names$last`**

```
List of 2
 $ 1:List of 2
  ..$ names:List of 2
  .. ..$ first: chr [1:3] "john" "lisa" "mike"
  .. ..$ last : chr [1:3] "johnsson" "larsson" "catell"
  ..$ stats:List of 2
  .. ..$ physical:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ age   : num [1:3] 14 22 23
  .. .. ..$ height: num [1:3] 165 176 182
  .. ..$ mental  :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ iq: num [1:3] 102 104 87
 $ 2:List of 2
  ..$ names:List of 2
  .. ..$ first: chr [1:2] "anna" "steven"
  .. ..$ last : chr [1:2] "johnsson" "larsson"
  ..$ stats:List of 2
  .. ..$ physical:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ age   : num [1:2] 53 31
  .. .. ..$ height: num [1:2] 179 191
  .. ..$ mental  :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ iq: num [1:2] 99 121
```

I`ve tried to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712843/split-list-by-id-and-store-results-into-seperate-vectors), but it appears that this won't work for nested lists.

**Reproducible code:**

```
L1 <- list("names" = list("first" = c("john","lisa","anna","mike","steven"),"last" = c("johnsson","larsson","johnsson","catell","larsson")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(14,22,53,23,31), "height" = c(165,176,179,182,191)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(102,104,99,87,121))))

L2 <- list("johnsson" = list("names" = list("first" = c("john","anna")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(14,53), "height" = c(165,179)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(102,99)))), "larsson" = list("names" = list("first" = c("lisa","steven")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(22,31), "height" = c(176,191)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(104,121)))), "catell" = list("names" = list("first" = "mike"),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = 23, "height" = 182), "mental" = list("iq" = 87))))

L3 <- list("1" = list("names" = list("first" = c("john","lisa","mike"),"last" = c("johnsson","larsson","catell")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(14,22,23), "height" = c(165,176,182)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(102,104,87)))), "2" = list("names" = list("first" = c("anna","steven"),"last" = c("johnsson","larsson")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(53,31), "height" = c(179,191)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(99,121)))))
```

**EDIT:** Please note that the actual dataset is quite large and more deeply nested than the provided example.

Comment: your data seems to be very structured, ie, rectangular, why arent you using a data frame

Comment: I didn't consider that when I created the sample data. The actual data i'm working with changes dynamically and isn't necessarily rectangular.

Comment: Could you provide an example where the non-list vectors don't all have the same lengths?  Along with the desired end result?

Answer (score 5):

Usually for modifying lists you will want to use recursion. For example, consider this function:

```
foo <- function(x, idx) {

    if (is.list(x)) {
        return(lapply(x, foo, idx = idx))
    }
    return(x[idx])
}
```

it takes some list as `x` and a number of indices `idx`. It will check if `x` is a list, and if that is the case it will lapply itself to all subelements of the list. Once `x` no longer is a list, we take the elements given by `idx`. During the whole process, the structure of the original list will remain intact.

Here a full example. Note that this code assumes all vectors in the list have 5 elements.

```
L1 <- list("names" = list("first" = c("john","lisa","anna","mike","steven"),"last" = c("johnsson","larsson","johnsson","catell","larsson")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(14,22,53,23,31), "height" = c(165,176,179,182,191)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(102,104,99,87,121))))

L2 <- list("johnsson" = list("names" = list("first" = c("john","anna")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(14,53), "height" = c(165,179)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(102,99)))), "larsson" = list("names" = list("first" = c("lisa","steven")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(22,31), "height" = c(176,191)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(104,121)))), "catell" = list("names" = list("first" = "mike"),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = 23, "height" = 182), "mental" = list("iq" = 87))))

L3 <- list("1" = list("names" = list("first" = c("john","lisa","mike"),"last" = c("johnsson","larsson","catell")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(14,22,23), "height" = c(165,176,182)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(102,104,87)))), "2" = list("names" = list("first" = c("anna","steven"),"last" = c("johnsson","larsson")),"stats" = list("physical" = list("age" = c(53,31), "height" = c(179,191)), "mental" = list("iq" = c(99,121)))))

# make L2
foo <- function(x, idx) {

    if (is.list(x)) {
        return(lapply(x, foo, idx = idx))
    }
    return(x[idx])
}

levels <- unique(L1$names$last)
L2_2 <- vector("list", length(levels))
names(L2_2) <- levels
for (i in seq_along(L2_2)) {

    idx <- L1$names$last == names(L2_2[i])
    L2_2[[i]] <- list(names = foo(L1$names[-2], idx),
                      stats = foo(L1$stats, idx))

}
identical(L2, L2_2)

str(L2)
str(L2_2)

# make L3

dups <- duplicated(L1$names$last)
L3_2 <- vector("list", 2)
names(L3_2) <- 1:2
for (i in 1:2) {

    if (i == 1)
        idx <- !dups
    else
        idx <- dups

    L3_2[[i]] <- foo(L1, idx)

}
identical(L3, L3_2)
str(L3)
str(L3_2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works fine with small lists but in the case of my dataset (~920 observations on ~50 variables) its not feasible.

Comment: Why is it not feasible? Time? Memory? Error?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer but I hope it helps.

See if this works for L3:

```
x = data.frame(L1, stringsAsFactors = F)
y = x[order(x$names.last),]
y$seq = 1
y$seq = ifelse(y$names.last == shift(y$names.last),shift(y$seq)+1,1)
y$seq[1] = 1

z = list(list(names=list(first=z[[1]]$names.first, last=z[[1]]$names.last), stats=list(physical = list(age =z[[1]]$stats.physical.age, height= z[[1]]$stats.physical.height), mental=list(iq= z[[1]]$stats.iq))), list(names=list(first=z[[2]]$names.first, last=z[[2]]$names.last), stats=list(physical = list(age =z[[2]]$stats.physical.age, height= z[[2]]$stats.physical.height), mental=list(iq= z[[2]]$stats.iq))))
```

The last part (`z`) where that transforms back into a list can be done with a loop. Assuming the same name doesn't come up too much the loop wouldn't be too slow.

You say it is more nested, in which case you will need to add `is.null` and or `tryCatch` functions to deal with errors.